# How do i generate accessible file url to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

my S3 bucket has no public access.

When i upload my file, it will appear in my s3 bucket.

For example:

**1-URL:**

```
"https://bucketName.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pathToFile/filename.pdf"
```

When i open this path, i receive this message:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>7G2D8VJSV3M10H92</RequestId>
<HostId>Cc5BwooOhvz6+A9DEByMRFUbBokFqvMWbsBl/QoCiPd/h2xBOr+TPQxigKHIeBpkos7RBGYtUxE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

That's perfect!

When i'm in the backend.. there is a button "open".. when i click this button i will see my file content:

**2-URL:**

```
https://bucketName.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pathToFile/filename.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=TZolawje222luX2VjEJX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDGV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMSJHMEUCIQCRQdTm3o0LnPzjljwuJceTpdU%2BzpZ1wUwNf1qa6MssJAIgebxp9b7gUWiF8rcyd22eOZ0o7%2Bfj36vKJz3AEbr0K9cq%2FwII3v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgw1NzEwMzk5MDgyNzAiDGSpmg0OULYO7wPPlyrTAlQnBekkDsdWKro14yeqCqsCaLejIY1xKljHX96Jv7Ks%2BJ5vQQ2DNg3z7oLrGIKROTln5lms3wo7AKN6pAvt0%2BE6t26dZ2hVqJQxYQJHxniwOSD47cpQZ74chNCH6uC6Q8u0r%2FNlgeOngfH%2BPWyQRCEtFUBFpqH%2BAfKw6KTooRdvJOBa1QLHcNrvqel5NugIYHoFVqiUUbJhcVEzHylIpTwwekySDHFV39nIOCbhu8yvU%2BCopoHLHgdeQD%2FJd50nVHUzsIMFuRMrDAXGuenS5eoUk7Ci%2FTR4%2FjHJ1cMDtY5%2FNf7axxqk7mojvJDavkvMNJdruR5uTLEYtKLo03Kb%2B6xp2EAhh1pzZz8hXtTrhpzzyaG5PInqs%2FH8fMeZcKChdVn8aBxqYQ0A3V9hE0LjlGsSoeHYqCgRqP2QG1GuYyPwXWmgm%2F%2F7mSfLJIESt8CBq1zCkj%2B%2BJBjqzAhLcYlBMrXIpyYBVIa1sP9QMvMtFp2JYjbvRBQV4SchBpS1j5GJQK3%2BpoBX9PeaPL8xvTvRrfoNuB3EZaUI9EgeDYYfHSDYU4F0Mqp%2B6g%2F5KopgrvAHqcx6sF%2F0QyYzkhsp7WpKyTdLzZBma7lydR6svgUBgS6E%2BkA307PzaE6jcuW9lD2Vof5VMy6ciIpBtziXGmSQJ1U6Pukrr%2BojDJ8NgdciL6TEiSRVwrZniIsj6aYPRFzv1Ro%2FCjDZQfDJ%2BhYrEKOcy28KW1ANiCOyloMBmBvMf6D53qTy%2BY7EZIGtIcP8nWl1Am5ESMKQq6QCErO2k731BqmdMdyqFAnNYrieji2JgK8%2B97STgNpYSEselvgpa47qhDvYlrqGBxyjdt0kLq%2FMvfQENd548P8Wf8sp61Ik%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210911T012328Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=EUROYJ5FKLWXJKTHAJPT%2F20210910%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=901db2f3543e69f05698ff4c45d188695376ea239cd9a262956bb701f10e06e0
```

I want to know how do i generate this 2-URL by myself?

In this url i see the "X-Amz-Security-Token" but i'm not sure where i get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic URL that lets you access a private Amazon S3 object is called an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.

You can generate a pre-signed URL with just a few lines of code. You can specify the time period for which the URL is valid. When generating the pre-signed URL, you will need to use a set of credentials that have permission to access the object. The 'signature' on the pre-signed URL comes from those credentials.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

The capability is available in programming languages via the AWS SDK. For example, in Python you would use  [Presigned URLs — Boto3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html). It is also available via the AWS CLI: [presign — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html)

Comment: thank you so much john! keyword "presigned url" is exactly what i was looking for :)